# Power apps Textbox input

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

How can I fill a Power app textbox as a result of of 5 dropdown selection?
Depending which selection you make on a dropdown, it should give you a statement definition inside the TextBox.
I have attached a picture to clarify.
Let me know if you need any more details.

Thanks a million!
Jose[image: image_description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write all the texts with conditions on the multiple selections and define the **default value** for the textbox. It will take a lot of manual work for sure.

For example, use the following formula on the **Text** property of the **Label** control:

```
If(And(ComboBox1.Selected.Value = "Shopfloor", ComboBox2.Selected.Value = "5S", ComboBox3.Selected.Value = "People & collaboration", ComboBox4.Selected.Value = "Level 1"), "All areas including EPU office footprint (under a roof or outside) is cut in reasonable zones on a layout (smaller chunks): clear territories Temporary footprint is available (For Pre-Serial). There is a 5S deployment plan displayed covering all the areas (within 1 year max)", "")
```

The Label control will display the sample contents once you define the required selections, or it remains empty.

For other conditions, trap the texts in the second **If** condition and so on.

References: [Defining default values for complex SharePoint types in forms.](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/pl-pl/blog/default-values-for-complex-sharepoint-types/) /
[Formula reference for Power Apps.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/formula-reference)

Comment: Chelsea, thanks a million for your support. 
I have tried for one statement, and it works nicely. However, there are over 1000 statements. It would be a great functionality to have. But time wise, it is not feasible.
Thanks again for support and help! :)